# How to reproduce UIDocumentUIPickerViewController NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, crashlytics, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I am presenting the `UIDocumentUIPickerViewController` from a view controller like this:

```swift
let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(
  documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF), String(kUTTypeImage)], 
  in: .import
)
documentPicker.delegate = self
documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Everything seems to work nicely. I select a file and get its URL in `documentPicker(controller:url:)`

But I am getting several crashes in Firebase like this:

> -[UIDocumentPickerViewController initForExportingURLs:asCopy:] must be called with a URL pointing to an existing file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 UserInfo (NSURL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/APP_ID/Documents/FILE.pdf, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/APP/
> Documents/FILE.pdf, (Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"))

Only >= iOS 16 users are affected, but I didn't manage to reproduce the error, and from what I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48007752/9451152), it seems to be an Apple issue.

It'd be nice to generate the error myself so that I can upload a fixed version to the App Store. But until I don't manage to reproduce the error, I can't prove that any solution is working.

I've tried to select big files with a feeble connection, but with no success...

Any ideas?

Comment: Since you are passing the `import` mode (note that the initializer you are using is deprecated) you should not be going through initForExportingURLs, which is used to save a file to eg iCloud Drive. This must be a different document picker view controller elsewhere in your app.

Comment: Strangely, this is the only occurrence of `UIDocumentPickerViewController` across the project. Could it be initialized indirectly from other places?

Comment: Do you think `QLPreviewController` can somehow initialize a `UIDocumentUIPickerViewController`?

Comment: Yes, if you tap "share" and then use "save to files". Have you filed a radar?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74376975/why-all-these-sharesheet-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thomas Deniau suggested in the comments, we managed to reproduce the bug by saving it to files. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74561084/9451152).